# PHP: loop for certain chunks of a total and then rest

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I'm not sure if I did this right:

I have a total number of items, say 624. I would like to make a loop that sends 7 requests, the first 6 over 100 items each, the last over the remaining 24.

So I did some math to find out how many loops I have to go through.

```
    // this is the total number of items
    $total = $result['total_items'];
    // if we split the total into such chunks
    $chunksize = 50;
    // we will get a rest of so many items
    $rest = $total % $chunksize;
    // so including the query for the rest, we will have to repeat the query so many times
    $queries_no = (($total-$rest)/$chunksize)+1;
```

**The above feels kinda clumsy. Is that the right way?**

PS: After that, I can repeat the query the necessary times.

```
    // prep loop
    $i = 0;
    $requested = 0;
    $subscribers = [];

    while ($i <= $queries_no){
        // last item
        if($i == $queries_no){
            $chunksize = $rest;
        }
        $result = $this->monkeyApp->get('lists/'.$list_id.'/members?offset='.$requested.'&count='.$chunksize);
        $subscribers = array_merge($subscribers,$result['members']);
        $requested = $requested + $chunksize;
        $i++;
    }
```

Comment: You should explain your task a bit more, there is no sense in "7 requests, the first 6 over 100 items each, the *third* (?) over the remaining 624".

Comment: Are you trying to implement "pagination"? Or are the 7 (?) chunks on one page?

Comment: `$queries_no = (int)floor(($total-1)/$chunksize)+1;` is probably simpler

Comment: Should have been " 7 requests, the first 6 over 100 items each, the last over the remaining 24" sorry, corrected it. Yes, "MonkeyApp" requires paginated queries, won't go over a certain amount of items per queries

Comment: why not `ceil($total/$chunksize)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
$subscribers = [];

for ($count = $chunksize, $offset = 0; $offset < $total; $offset += $chunksize)
{
    if ($offset + $chunksize > $total)
    {
        $count = $total % $chunksize;
    }

    $result = $this->monkeyApp->get("lists/$list_id/members?offset=$offset&count=$count");

    $subscribers = array_merge($subscribers, $result['members']);
}
```